# How to redirect category products to different website?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, redirect, 301-redirect

I have 100's of products that needs to be redirected to a different website when the customer clicks on a product on category page, because I want to sell them there. Is it possible with Magento. Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: you have to do this change using programmatically in core phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Yo can create new attribute, lets say 'Redirect'

and change in template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
if($product->getRedirect())
{
   //set anchor with $product->getRedirect() link
}
else
{
   //core functionality (Product page url)
}
```

Comment: if you find above ans use full then please mark it as approved.